# Let $V$ be a vector space finitely generated over a field $F$ and let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be proper subspaces of $V$ satisfying $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a vector space finitely generated over a field $F$ and let $W_1$ and $W_2$ be
proper subspaces of $V$ satisfying $V = W_1 \oplus W_2$. Show that $D(V) = E_1 \oplus E_2$,
where $E_j = \{\delta \in D(V ) \;|\;W_j \subseteq \text{ker}(\delta)\}$ for $j = 1, 2$.

Any ideas/help are greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is $\,D\left(V\right)$?

Comment: The dual space of V aka V*